# Conditionally modify array element without resorting to a temporary array

Tags: arrays, powershell

Given an array like this

```
$array = @('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
```

I can append something to the end of each item in the array like so

```
$array = $array | Foreach-Object {"$_ *"}
```

And if I want to append something DIFFERENT to each member I can do so like this

```
$tempArray = @()
$count = 1
foreach ($item in $array) {
    $tempArray += "$item $count"
    $count ++
}
$array = $tempArray
```

But that use of a temporary array seems... clumsy. I feel like I am missing something that would allow conditionally changing the values of the original array instead. Not adding new items, just changing the value of existing items.

Comment: You are wanting to change or append? What do you hope to end up with?

Comment: @doug-maurer, I want to append to the end of the current value. So the final array is 
A 1,
B 2,
C 3,
D 4,
E 5

Comment: I added example for both appending the value and appending a space and a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options here

1: set the result of the foreach to the variable you are iterating. this will iterate the array and set the result to the same variable.

```
$count = 1
$array = foreach ($item in $array) {
    "$item $count"
    $count ++
}
```

2: set an array element like so (note array elements begin by 0 not 1)

```
$array[2] = 'foo'
```

or in a loop like like so. this will set each variable at iteration.

```
$append = 'a'
for($i=0;$i -lt $array.count;$i++){
    $array[$i] = $array[$i],$append -join ' '
    $append += 'a'
}
```

Comment: Aha. I think the thing I was missing was your first example, setting the `$array =` to the result of the loop. I had just been doing the loop and trying to set `$item =`. For more complex conditions where I am not already creating an index variable, this seems better.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add @(), it's already an array as

```
$array = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'
```

If you simply want to append to the string and store back into the array, this is how I would do it. I'm taking advantage of the -Begin, -Process, and -OutVariable parameters of Foreach-Object.

```
$array | ForEach{$count = 1}{$_ + $count++} -OutVariable array
```

Output (also stored back in $array)

```
A1
B2
C3
D4
E5
```

Now if you did actually want to append a space before the number, then simply add that to the item like this

```
$array | ForEach{$count = 1}{"$_ " + $count++} -OutVariable array
```

Output

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
E 5
```

If you need to control the data flow more explicitly I would still lean towards not using for loops. This is equivalent.

```
$array = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'
$array = 1..$array.Count | ForEach{$array[$_-1] + " $_"}
```

or you could also write it as

```
$array = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'
$array = 1..$array.Count | ForEach{"$($array[$_-1]) $_"}
```

Comment: Neat, I didn't know the -outVariable trick. I can see that coming in handy. For my immediate needs I thinkGuenther's first solution below is going to allow me to handle the complex conditionals my real code needs. But all three will have their place in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to be what you're after:

```
$array = @('A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
for ($c=1; $c -le $array.count; $c++) {
    Write-host "$($array[$c-1]) $c"
}
```